# Script to get image url of a given tweet

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping, twitter

Using python, I want to automatically get the image source of a given tweet (example: [tweet](https://twitter.com/Avaaz/status/1102112466283175936)), in order to show it (the image) in a dashboard. If you click on the image you will get the tweet url + '/photo/1'. However this can not be downloadable. If you right click on the image (get image source). You will get a link to the image url (https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D0t9bz_XgAAl3hD?format=jpg&name=large), but this link can't be guessed for a automated coding. Any suggestion on how to automatically download or get a tweet image source ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the ID of the Tweet, in this case `1102112466283175936`

You can use the Twitter API to get the Tweet object. The image information is in the `includes` data.

The API query is via the `/2/tweets/:id` endpoint, and the path to the image URL is `includes.media.url`. For example:

```
$ twurl -j "/2/tweets/1102112466283175936?media.fields=url&expansions=attachments.media_keys"
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "attachments": {
      "media_keys": [
        "3_1102112450588147712"
      ]
    },
    "id": "1102112466283175936",
    "text": "5000 selfies make up this iconic image of @jeremycorbyn in today's @ObserverUK, calling on him to bring courage and leadership to unite @UKLabour MPs behind a #PublicVote on #Brexit. RT to support! [shortened link]"
  },
  "includes": {
    "media": [
      {
        "media_key": "3_1102112450588147712",
        "type": "photo",
        "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D0t9bz_XgAAl3hD.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You could use the Tweepy library to access the API from Python. Other API libraries are available.